# Android custom enum for xml tag

Tags: android, xml, enums, tags

I want to declare enum somewhere in xml/java class, no matter.
Just simple

```
enum myEnum {
    FIRST,
    SECOND
}
```

Or declare it somehow in xml.
And then use it in xml.
What I need as result:

```
<TextView>
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="myEnum/FIRST"
</TextView>

<Button>
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="myEnum/SECOND"
</Button>
```

etc.
Is something like that possible?

PS. I need something, that would work with any standart view.

Comment: hey Eugene, did you manage to find the solution for that?

Comment: Nope, I believe there is no standard solution for this. I used tag with @string resource. Also you can see Calligraphy approach, it's quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

In attrs.xml add following:

```
  <declare-styleable name="TextView">
    <attr name="font" format="enum">
        <enum name="light" value="0" />
        <enum name="normal" value="1" />
        <enum name="bold" value="2" />
        <enum name="roboto_light" value="3" />
        <enum name="roboto_regular" value="4" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Use in following way in custom text view:

```
package com.rxmedicalapp.customviews;


public class TextView extends AppCompatTextView {
public TextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(null);
}

public TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);
}

public TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(attrs);
}


private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextView);
        int fontCode = a.getInt(R.styleable.TextView_font,Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        Typeface myTypeface=null;
        switch (fontCode){
            case 0:
                myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/helvetica_light.ttf");
                break;

            case 1:
                myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/helvetica_regular.ttf");
                break;

            case 2:
                myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/helvetica_bold.ttf");
                break;

            case 3:
                myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/robotolight.ttf");
                break;

            case 4:
                myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/robotoregular.ttf");
                break;

            default:
                myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/robotoregular.ttf");
                break;



        }

        setTypeface(myTypeface);

        a.recycle();
    }
}

public void setUnderLine(boolean underlined){


}
```

}

Comment: I know about styleable, but it works with custom views. What I need is similar enum, that would be working with any standart view.

Comment: How would it be useful, as it won't be handled by standard views.

When we extends standard views we have to handle custom xml attributes manually in extended class.

Comment: For example, I want to put such tag to any view and then use it to define typeface for that view.

Comment: for that you must have to extend TextView and handle your custom tag in java like I updated in the above answer.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a good option! But what about Buttons, Edittexts etc.? In that case I would have to extend each of those classes.

Answer (score 1):

In simple way just set tag in String format then when you want to use it as enum then convert it to enum value by this:

```
myEnum tag = myEnum.valueOf(view.getTag().toString());
```

And you can use it for switch ..case or anywhere you want.
Hope this helps others.